# wordpress double quotes issue in editor

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, html

I am having strange issue while using **double quotes inside H3** tag.The opening quotes getting mess as in image .

[image]

wordpress version : 3.2

Editor            :tinyMCE 3.3.9.3

present page url  : http://cratecreative.com/goldburdmccone/free-case-evaluation/

Thanks

Comment: When you turn off javascript, it looks fine.  Are you using javascript to load a special font?

Comment: @keoki:I am not really sure , I am using eco bidz theme.

Comment: @gowri I took at look at your site's javascript code, you are indeed loading a special font.  I don't know why it's causing that problem, but if you can get by without it, then you're page will look fine.  Do you know how to use Firefox Firebug?  If you inspect the header with it, you'll see that the javascript turns the H3 into a bunch of canvas elements, kind of weird.

Comment: @keoki:Yes i got your point . cufon font is applying . can i overcome from this. is there any solution exist ?

Comment: @gowri by the way, the custom font doesn't seem to work in IE 9, have you tried it out yourself yet?

Comment: @gowri I think I may have found a solution for you, check out my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400511/h1-and-h2-classes-not-showing-up-in-internet-explorer, let me know if that fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cause of Problem

It appears that the misalignment of the quotation marks is due to your h3 elements being replaced by the `cufon-yui.js` script by canvas elements, because when I disable JavaScript on your site, I notice that the quotation marks are then properly aligned (so it has nothing to do with your CSS).

## Additional Problem: IE9 Incompatibility

I've also found through my research on cufon for [another SO problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400511/h1-and-h2-classes-not-showing-up-in-internet-explorer) that it sometimes does not work in IE9, which I have confirmed is the case for your site.  Depending on which version of IE9 you're using, the h3 and other header elements on your site won't show up at all.

## Possible Solutions

### Fix 1. Upgrade Cufon

According to [Cufon's FAQ](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/FAQ), item #8, the IE9 incompatability issue was fixed in a newer version of their code (which you might not be using), and it's available for download from their main site:

> This was fixed in 1.09i. Just download
>   a new cufon-yui.js from the official
>   site and you’re good to go. It’s fully
>   backwards-compatible too.

Upgrading to the newer solution of Cufon might solve your quotation mark misalignment issue too, but I'm not sure.

### Fix 2. Use IE Conditional Comments

According to the same Cufon FAQ, if you don't want to upgrade your Cufon version, you can place the following code in your html before the calls to `Cufon.replace()`:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Cufon.set('engine', 'canvas');
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

As an alternative, they also give instructions on how to force IE9 to behave like IE7 or 8.

These solutions should fix the IE9 incompatibility problem, but I'm not sure if they'll fix the quotation mark misalignment issue.

### Fix 3. Use Typekit Instead

You may also be interested in trying [Typekit](http://typekit.com/) instead, which according to the [cufon main site](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/), also has the advantage of the text being selectable, which it currently isn't using Cufon:

> You might also want to take this
>   opportunity to [try Typekit][1], a hosted,
>   @font-face-based alternative. Yes,
>   that means they support text
>   selection. It's the easiest way to
>   embrace standards.

Using Typekit will definitely solve the problem of your header elements not showing up in IE 9, and might solve the quotation mark misalignment issue too.

### Fix 4. Remove Special Fonts Entirely

You also always have the option of just not using one of these JavaScript-injected special fonts at all.