# IE9 h2 li a tag not showing up

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Our Blog site seems to work fine on all browsers. Recently one of the readers reported that he is not able to see the Questions on this page : [Java Blog Page](http://www.fromdev.com/2008/05/java-threading-questions.html)

I used the BrowserShots to debug this and found that IE9 and IE10 Both have this problem

http://browsershots.org/screenshots/1f1d2c6aa3b54e1423f5c344d2b1e21e

I am sure this is some problem with a CSS and IE may be treating it badly.

Any known issues or Bugs that I can take care of?

I have already tried the two related issues on

[SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400511/h1-and-h2-classes-not-showing-up-in-internet-explorer)

[Other Forum](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/4327604.htm)

Nothing seems to work so far

Comment: You can't just nest an <li> in an <h2>, it needs a <ul> wrapper

Comment: The document doesn't validate (300+ errors, some of them significant). Particularly, the markup of the list/headings is invalid: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fromdev.com%2F2008%2F05%2Fjava-threading-questions.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: You should have the h2 in the `li`, not the `li` in the `h2`. `<ul><li><h2>..</h2></li>...</ul>`

Comment: @Tim Thanks - Its a blogger blog, and we have customized the theme big time. There may be a lot of issues. Will look into it. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Musa - Thanks for your response. Another follow up on your suggestion. What about the <a> tag? where should that live.. is <li><a><h2> the right sequence? or <li><h2><a>

Comment: @Kzvi `<li><h2><a>...</a><h2></li>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that your document is structured to achieve automatic numbering. However, it's debatable if this is really an appropriate use of an ordered list.

Two solutions come to mind:

- manual numbering (it's not a big list)
- [CSS-based counters](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters)

If you decide to continue using an ordered list, then [fix the markup to be valid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.fromdev.com/2008/05/java-threading-questions.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). At minimum, `LI` must be the direct child of `OL`, not nested within other elements.

Corrected markup sample which validates: http://jsfiddle.net/adCz7/

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Here is a paragraph</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Test</h2>
        <p>Here is a paragraph</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Your ordered list `<ol>` element can have `<li>` children, but the other content should be nested in the `<li>`.  As the other poster said, you may be better off manually numbering in this case to avoid the malformed markup you're currently using which seems to be confusing IE's rendering engine.

Comment: Thanks this seems to real problem. I have several blog post and a template that generates the list tags and h2, a tags. It would be much easier for me to fix the format than adding numbering since every new post would be manually numbered. Will try your options and revert back with feedback. Thanks

Comment: Excellent. Its working now. Looks like I need to get rid of the li tags and go for the css counter options. However your answers cover it all so I am going to accept it. Thanks a lot everyone for your time and help. I appreciate it.